# JPQL - left join with count for many in one-to-many

Tags: java, count, left-join, jpql, spring-data

Spent about 2 hours trying to understand why JPQL query doesn't return me what I expect. Please consider the code:

```
    System.out.println("JPQL ----------------------------");
    Query q = em.createQuery(
            "select u.userName, count(p.id) from User u " + 
            "left join u.posts p group by u.userName");
    List x = q.getResultList();     
    for(Object o : x) {
        Object[] y = (Object[])o;
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", y[0], y[1]);
    }

    System.out.println("Spring Data JPA -----------------");
    for(User user : userRepository.findAll()) {
        List<Post> posts = postRepository.findAllByAuthor(user);
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", user.getUserName(), posts.size());
    }
```

Output is:

```
JPQL ----------------------------
user1 0
user2 0
Spring Data JPA -----------------
user1 3
user2 10
```

I expect JPQL approach to print the same as what repository approach does. Where's the mistake?

**Update**

Here's what SQL trace says:

```
select 
  user0_.userName as col_0_0_, 
  count(post2_.id) as col_1_0_ 
from User user0_ 
left outer join User_Post posts1_ 
  on user0_.id=posts1_.User_id 
left outer join Post post2_ 
  on posts1_.posts_id=post2_.id 
group 
  by user0_.userName
```

Comment: Just a guess (haven't used Hibernate in a long time): try getting rid of the `group by` in the JPQL.

Comment: @MattBall: says SQLGrammarException :-(

Comment: I am not familiar with JPQL but you are not specifying `join condition` I mean on what basis tables should be joined.

Comment: JPQL uses the JPA defined associations to determine the join condition so it's not specified as a part of the query.

Comment: @Smit: condition is described by `u.posts` - there's a one-to-many relationship between user and posts.

Comment: @digitaljoel Thanks for information. I think I need to get start working on spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query was correct, but there was issue with relationships definition. Here's what I had:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...         
    @OneToMany
    private List<Post> posts;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private User author;
    ...
}
```

It appeared that I have to specify relationship between `User` and `Post` like this:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Post> posts;
```